# Самый простой способ перевода (локализации) интерфейса  drupal и модулей

Tags: drupal

С помощью каких модулей можно быстро произвести перевод друпала со всеми модулями?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@vadim-kot](/users/18353/vadim-kot)](/users/18353/vadim-kot), для перевода интерфейса drupal существует несколько решений-модулей, но, на мой взгляд, самый удобный способ с помощью модуля  Localization update, его можно также использовать в связке с drush, если нужно подробнее, то вот статья [перевод drupal](http://drup.by/articles/perevod-drupal-i-moduley-na-russkiy-lokalizaciya). В ней все расписано подробно.

Comment: спасибо, вроде подходит